# Hooks are not being removed in child theme

Tags: hooks, actions

I have a hook file:

```
function load_admin_package(){
    do_action('load_admin_package');
}

/*
 * -----------------------------------
 * Define hooks bellow
 * -----------------------------------
 */

function load_admin(){
    $package = new AisisCore_Loader_Package();
    $package->load_package('AdminPanel', CORETHEME);
}


/*
 * -----------------------------------
 * Asign hooks bellow
 * -----------------------------------
 */

add_action('load_admin_package', 'load_admin');
```

Very simple, very straight forward. This resides in the parent theme. this file is then required into the functions.php file.

In the child functions.php I do:

```
function remove_hooks(){
    remove_action('load_admin_package', 'load_admin');
}

add_action('after_theme_setup', 'remove_hooks');
```

`load_admin` essentially loads the admin options page for the parent theme. However in the child theme I am removing it so it doesn't load. Problem? The `remove_action()` returns `true`, yet in the child theme admin I still have access to the admin options which should not exist...

What's going on?

Comment: Have you tried the correct action `after_setup_theme`?

Comment: Also maybe not post in multiple places, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445686/why-is-this-true-but-not-being-removed

Comment: i need answers right away hence the posting every where. I dont have time to wait